# python pandas - return a list or a serie of values in each cell

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called 'trade' such as follow:

```
                        high              MFE_ts
exit_time                                       
2000-02-01 01:00:00  1401.50 2000-02-01 01:00:00
2000-02-01 01:30:00  1401.00 2000-02-01 01:30:00
2000-02-01 02:00:00  1401.00 2000-02-01 01:30:00
2000-02-01 02:30:00  1399.75 2000-02-01 02:30:00
2000-02-01 03:00:00  1400.00 2000-02-01 02:30:00
2000-02-01 03:30:00  1399.25 2000-02-01 03:30:00
2000-02-01 04:00:00  1399.00 2000-02-01 03:30:00
2000-02-01 04:30:00  1400.25 2000-02-01 03:30:00
2000-02-01 05:00:00  1400.50 2000-02-01 03:30:00
2000-02-01 05:30:00  1400.75 2000-02-01 03:30:00
```

I want to add a new column to the right that will contain a Serie of values that should be as follow:

For each row take the timestamp contained in the 'MFE_ts' column and create a list of values taken from the 'high' column that will span from that timestamp to the end of the table.
For instance in the last row, the output should be `= trade.loc['2000-02-01 03:30:00':, 'high']`

I have tried varous iteration of the following

```
trade[MAE_pr] = trade.loc[trade['MFE_ts']:, 'high']
```

but without success. I assume a serie or a list would be fine - i eventually want to apply a max() or min() function to that serie/list, for each cell in that new column MAE_pr.

Comment: Are you trying to solve your question from yesterday this way?

Comment: yes... im new to stack overflow so apologize if i dont ask my questions in the sharpest way from the get go. You guys have been amazing help so far.

Comment: Don't do that. You are cloning questions into others, and you are inferring potential solutions you think of instead of setting the problem correctly to get the most appropriate answer. One trick for instance: I didn't see you added a comment in your previous post and edited it. Mention people in comments so that they receive alerts. I'll answer to your original question soon. I would recommend to delete that one as it will lead you to bigger issues: you should not store series inside pandas cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
df.apply(lambda x: df.high.loc[x.MFE_ts:], 1)
```

[image]

Comment: I managed to retrieve the min() of the serie created using `df.apply(lambda x: df.high.loc[x.MFE_ts:].min(), 1)`
However, if i try to retrieve now the index by using`df.apply(lambda x: df.high.loc[x.MFE_ts:].idxmin(), 1)`, i receive the error message `invalid type promotion` . Would you know why?